# Infer type of variable based on type of key

Tags: typescript

I want to infer type of variable based on the type of a key during assignment.

The code would look maybe something like this. (The below code does not work though.).

```
const ONE = '1';
const TWO = 2;

type A = { id: typeof ONE };
type B = { id: typeof TWO };

type ONETWO = typeof ONE | typeof TWO;

type AB<T = { id: ONETWO }> = T extends { id: typeof ONE }
  ? A
  : T extends { id: typeof TWO }
  ? B
  : never;

const a: AB = { id: ONE }; // typeof a *should be* A but is never
const b: AB = { id: TWO }; // typeof b *should be* B but is never
```

I know that conditional types can be used to infer types when passed to functions. But, is is possible to infer types during assignment?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You have to specify a generic argument.

Comment: Is this a [mre] of the issue? Right now it looks like you just want a union, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Na5RoN).  If you want something else, please motivate it with an example that requires generic conditional types.